# Let a cardview look disabled - Is there a default/preferred look?

Tags: android, android-cardview

How can I make a `cardview`look disabled? Is there some default background resource, that supports this? A design guide line?

Currently I'm removing the elevation and changing the background to gray...

Is there a default way to display that a `cardview` is disabled?

Comment: No, there is no disabled state for CardView. You could set a foreground drawable which could dimm the entire card. Furthermore you could override and return false onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent to prevent touch input on it's child views.

Comment: did you find any method to achieve this? please share.

Comment: No. I manually change it's look...